# PHP: преобразование SOAP ответа к SimpleXMLElement

Tags: php, xml, soap

Добрый день!

Задача следующая, имеется клиент, который общается с сервером через SOAP. Необходимо ответ интерпретировать как XML (для дальнейшего разбора). 
Код, которым отправляю запрос и обрабатываю ответ:

```
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_enabled', '0'); 
ini_set('soap.wsdl_cache_ttl', '0'); 

$client = new SoapClient($wsdl , array( 'exceptions' => 1,'trace' => 1,'login' => $login, 'password' => $password); 
var_dump( $client->__getFunctions());

$params["Login"] = '123';
$params["Password"] = '2134';
$result = $client->GetLogin($params);

$xml=$client->__getLastResponse();
$doc= simplexml_load_string($xml);
```

echo $xml возвращает:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<Request> <Status>Confirm</Status> 
<Message>Авторизация прошла успешно!</Message> 
<ID>279f6b3a-0a13-11e7-a67e-0050568623d9</ID> </Request>
```

print_r($doc) возвращает:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object ( )
```

Т.е. на выходе создался пустой объект. Ошибок через libxml_get_errors не увидел.

В чем может быть проблема? Почему объект не создался корректно?

Спасибо!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/simplexmlelement.asxml.php вам в помощь

Comment: Не очень понял, как мне это поможет.  Что интересно, если задать переменную жестко $xml='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <Request> <Status>Confirm</Status> <Message>Авторизация прошла успешно!</Message> <ID>279f6b3a-0a13-11e7-a67e-0050568622d9</ID> </Request> ';  То все в дальнейшем отрабатывает успешно. Можете, пожалуйста, чуть подробнее прокоментировать Ваш совет?

Answer (score 2):

Всем спасибо за помощь. Проблема оказалась значительно проще, чем я тут описал.

Дело в том, что SOAP response возвращает в блоке return XML в виде строки, а не с тэгами. 
Поэтому print_r ($result)/var_dump выводил конечный результат экранируя тэги. Что реально содержится в этой переменной можно было записал ее в файл. 
В итоге было достаточно сделать:
$ParamsUsr = new SimpleXMLElement($result->return);

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте так

```
$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);  $output = $sxe->asXML();
```